# Is it okey to show firebase storage item url to user?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am making a app where user can upload any image and get a link for that image. By using that  link user can share that image something like imgur site. For this purpose I am using firebase storage. Now the thing is that link is containing some information and now I'm worrying the user might exploit things.

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/"myappname".appspot.com/o/Image.png?alt=media&token="some token number"
```

So my question is, Is it possible for anyone to exploit or do any harmful thing through above link?. I'm not using any authentication rules for storage.

Answer (score 2):

What you're showing is a download URL to a file in Cloud Storage. Anyone that has this URL can read the file associated with it, regardless of the security rules you've set up.

That is precisely the level of abuse you're opening yourself up for when you share this URL with someone: they can read the file, and/or share the URL with others who can then do the same.

This is the same as when you'd give them the URL to another file that is hosted on a service you own - and which is not secured.

Comment: Thank you Frank, But I am not concern with the file that attach with url as its user's property and he should decide with whom he want to share. My actual concern is that url contains my app name with which I have project in firebase and url contain token number. By knowing these things is there any threat to my app or firebase project or to the other stored files. or any other kind of threat?

Comment: It's impossible to answer for "any kind of threat", but for the file the scope of abuse is as I said in my answer.